# Rate module Thumbs Counter

Tags: theming, rating

I've installed the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) Module in order to add a simple thumbs up/down rating system on nodes. By default it displays the average percentage (see below) but all I want is to display a simple counter of up/down votes.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the file:

```
rate-template-thumbs-up-down.tpl.php
```

that you find in the module rate/templates/thums-up-down to your theme's template folder.

Then change these two lines that print out the percentage:

```
<div class="percent"><?php print $results['up_percent'] . '%'; ?></div>
...
<div class="percent"><?php print $results['down_percent'] . '%'; ?></div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="percent"><?php print $results['up']; ?></div>
...
<div class="percent"><?php print $results['down']; ?></div>
```

Comment: Cheers buddy, works perfectly :)